# How to use switch case in selenium to test several web element in a page?

Tags: java, selenium

i have a webpage with several element to be tested.
They are more than 100 and i could not write 100 code to test one element.
Is it possible to use switch case to test the element i want and not all.

For example here i have 3 tests to be executed, what i want is to test only Test1 and Test2, how can i do this using switch case in java, because i have more than 100 tests to be executed, i want to use only one code.

Thank you

```
 //TEST1
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(CmpList._google)).isDisplayed();
        System.out.println("Google Tab exists");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(CmpList._google)).click();

        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("TEST FAILED--Google Tab element does not exist");
        } finally {
        System.out.println("Continue");
        }


    //TEST2
        try {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(CmpList._radio)).isDisplayed();
        System.out.println("Radio Tab element exists");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(CmpList._radio)).click();

        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("TEST FAILED--Radio Tab element does not exist");
        } finally {
        System.out.println("Continue");
        }

 //TEST3
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(CmpList._yahoo)).isDisplayed();
        System.out.println("Google Tab exists");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(CmpList._yahoo)).click();

        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("TEST FAILED--Yahoo Tab element does not exist");
        } finally {
        System.out.println("Continue");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] testsToTest = {1,2, 45, ...};
int currentTest;
for(int i = 0; i < testsToTest; i++){
    currentTest = testsToTest[i];
    Switch (currentTest){
     case 1:
        //your first test
        break;
     case 2:
        //second test
        break;
     ...
     case 100;
        //100th test
        break;
     default: System.out.println("unknown test");
    }
}
```

That'll at least get you off the ground. There's definitely a nicer way to write this here, I shutter to think how long your file will become. perhaps you could use a more generic method since you're basically testing element x, and either clicking x or saying "x failed". Consider having a map of test numbers and xpaths. for example:

```
public boolean testElement(String xpath){
    try {
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).isDisplayed();
            element.click();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("TEST FAILED--element with xpath " + xpath + " does not exist");
    } finally {
            System.out.println("Continue");
    }
}
```

And then you could have a hashmap of testNumbers and their xpath. Then it would just be a matter of iterating over the list as above, but instead of the switch, it would just be

`testElement(testMap.get(testToTest[i]))`

Comment: Thank you for your answers, i tried to to seperate each test with java file and use Junit with RunWith and SuiteClasses, here i can choose which test i want to use but still i have 100 java files. But i don't understand the example with hashmap, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the only thing that changes is the XPath and the message you are printing.

It's not clear from your code, but if you're not using a test framework like JUnit or TestNG, then you should be.

[JUnitParams](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams) is a good candidate for this as it offers a way to pass a collection of parameters to a test method and execute it many times. Each execution is treated as a separate test, without the need to write repetitive code. If the first test fails, it will continue to run the other tests.

One example usage (there are many options):

```
@Test
@Parameters({ 
        CmpList._radio, 
        CmpList._yahoo,
        .... })
public void shouldFindElement(String xpath) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).isDisplayed();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(CmpList._radio)).click();
}
```

Personally, I don't think you should catch the Exception as is not expected. I also think that you print statements introduce noise.